# Should we disable compiler optimization until the program is bug free?

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-construction

Sometimes compiler optimization hides errors; for exemple:

```
double val = sin(1.5);
```

If the compiler optimization is enabled although the math library is not linked this will compile since the compiler will calculate the value of `sin(1.5)` and replace it.

Is it a good practice to disable compiler optimization until the program is bug free?

Comment: You mean there exists such a thing as bug-free code?

Comment: That's arguably not a bug, then...

Comment: On the other hand, compiler optimization sometimes *highlights* errors, at least in languages with undefined behaviour that can be exploited by optimizations (C, C++).

Comment: While you are debugging your code (using a debugger), the compiler usually disables many optimizations, to esier match your source code to the actual running machine code, so you can step through your source or machine code. So, if you are using tools like integratted debugging, you may be actually running a non optimized code.

Comment: Linking doesn't happen until after compilation has occurred, so no amount of disabling compiler optimizations will cause compilation to fail because of an unlinked library.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: The OP is quite right. When the compiler optimizes away the function call (by precomputing the result), it prevents the linker error.

Comment: @ruakh: The OP is not right. "If the compiler optimization is enabled although the math library is not linked this will compile" - it certainly will compile, but it will also compile if compiler optimization is not enabled, too, because linking libraries happens after compilation. If this were not true, incremental compilation would be impossible, and we all know that it is possible. There's nothing inherent in C that requires an actual separate standard library archive, so failing to link one is not a "bug" or an "error" in your "program". It's just a failure to use your tools properly.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: O.K., I see what you're saying. The OP's statements are all technically correct, and his/her overall point is also correct; but what you're pointing out is his/her mistaken implication that a linker error will make something "not compile" (when in fact it will make it "not link"). Do I have that right?

Comment: @ruakh: More importantly the mistaken implication that a line of code such as `double val = sin(1.5);` becomes an "error" as a result of failing to link a library, which would be a fundamental misunderstanding of the process of turning C source code into programs. If you turn on compiler optimizations during the development process, you're hardly going to turn them off when you do your release build, so when exactly would this become a problem? That's right - when, and only when, you implement the purported "good practice". The described case is simply not an "error".

Comment: Or, put another way, it's not an "error" to fail to link a library in circumstances, like those described in the original post, where that library is not required to be linked, any more than it's an "error" to fail to link libm on an implementation that doesn't even have a separate libm.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: O.K., yeah, that makes sense. (A "good practice" is only useful if it prevents an error that wouldn't be detected until runtime; a linker error prevents itself.) But I don't know how you expected anyone to divine that from your original comment. :-)

Comment: @ruakh: That's fair enough, I guess it does require a leap or two to get from the beginning to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Since nobody wrote it up as an answer, I take a shot.</sub>

> Is it a good practice to disable compiler optimization until the program is bug free?

I wouldn't recommend it. Instead, **I would regularly test my code in release mode** as well (with optimizations enabled). I have had some bugs personally and I have seen many cases where **the code worked beautifully in debug mode but crashed or produced weird things in release mode**. (Some of the latter bugs were stack corruption related.)

The sooner you realize that you have such a bug, the better. You will probably have an easier time finding it while your memories of the code are still fresh.

Another thing I have seen is bugs due to side effects in code snippets that only run in debug mode. These are clearly the developer's mistake but the sooner you notice it, the more likely that you will have an easier time fixing it.

Developing in release mode unless I need the debugger seems a little over the top to me. In debug mode you may get many useful checks in your third party libraries which in turn reduces your time spent on debugging.

In short: develop in debug mode but test regularly in release mode.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the following argument: All code that is deployed, is optimized. So there is little point in hampering down the development process by unnecessarily using unoptimized code. Especially, it does not make sense to do *any* performance evaluation with unoptimized code. The only reason for switching off the optimizer is to be able to follow the program in a debugger, nothing else. If switching off optimization breaks the build, that's a nuisance, nothing more.

Much worse is the opposite effect where a program suddenly fails due to optimization. That is the effect you need to safeguard against, because that is the effect your users will get angry about. And due to the combination of clever optimizers and undefined behaviour in the language definition, this effect can happen quite easily.

So I try to do all my testing at least with `-O2`, and switch to `-O0` only when I need to use the debugger.